# p:dataTable print blank line after click p:commandButton using BaseDataModel

Tags: java, primefaces, datatables

I have a one p:commandLink

```
<p:commandLink id="btAdicionar"
    action="#{myBean.addDocs}"                  
    update="messagesDialog myDataTable">                    
</p:commandLink>
```

MyDataTable is this:

```
<p:dataTable 
    id="myDataTable" 
    widgetVar="myDataTable" 
    var="documentoEnvio" 
    width="600px"
    emptyMessage="Selecione documento(s)"
    paginator="true" paginatorPosition="bottom" rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15" paginatorAlwaysVisible="true" styleClass="ui-tj-datagrid"
    selection="#{myBean.documentosSelecionadosEnvio}" 
    value="#{myBean.listaDocumentosEnvio}" rows="#{msgs['grid.row.default']}" currentPageReportTemplate="#{msgs['grid.currentPageReportTemplate.of']} {totalPage}"
    paginatorTemplate="#{msgs['grid.label.exibir']} {RowsPerPageDropdown} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} #{msgs['grid.label.JumpToPageDropdown']} {JumpToPageDropdown} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}">
<p:column id="tipoDocumento2" styleClass="ui-normal-column-header" headerText="Tipo Documento">
                    <h:outputText value="#{documentoEnvio.tipoDocumentoHabilitacao.descricao}" escape="false" style="text-align: center !important; display: block;" />
                </p:column>     

...</p:dataTable>
```

My Bean

```
public void adicionarDocumentosSelecionados(){
listaDocumentoEditalEnvio = new ArrayList<DocumentoHabilitacao>();

        Set<DocumentoHabilitacao> setdListDocumentoListHabilitcao = new HashSet<DocumentoHabilitacao>();;

        for(int i=0; i < documentosSelecionados.length; i++ ){

            setdListDocumentoListHabilitcao.add(documentosSelecionados[i]);                     
        }

        listaDocumentoEditalEnvio.addAll(setdListDocumentoListHabilitcao);
        listaDocs = new ArrayList<DocumentoHabilitacao>();
        listaDocs = listaDocumentoEditalEnvio;
        listaDocumentosEnvio = new BaseDataModel<DocumentoHabilitacao>(listaDocs, DocumentoHabilitacao.class);
}
```

the values loaded ok. But not appear in p:daatTable. show a blank line:

[PICTURE >>> Before click button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YJ7B.png)

[PICTURE >>> After click button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q1oj4.png)

Comment: did you check if actually the dataTable is empty or something like that

Comment: Yes, i checked. the value p:dataTable is not  null. The dataTable show empty value message before click button 'search'. After click button,  dataTable show a line blank

Comment: the most commun error when getting empty rows is that you don't bind data correctly search about if you get empty informations

Comment: the same occurrence for static values. i create ArrayList <String> with  static values. The datatable don't show lines, but show pages number and this ArrayList object is loaded in execution time (debug).  When click the button the pages count change for 60 for 300 objects in array. The object is loaded in memory. But don't show values in datatable. The problem in a ajax? RequestContext?

Comment: i added  picture

Comment: RESOLVED the problem is a selector. Don't function, i removed selector tag.